# Custom styling Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have customized Bootstrap style a little. Basically, it's just "blue" variable. Here are a few pictures. First, Navigation bar that is defined like this:

```
class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-primary navbar-fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md"
```

This picture show its background.

[image]

I am also using Bootstrap 4 Accordion. Here is its code:

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Straight from the docs.

In my app it looks like this:

[image]

Shouldn't Accordion headers match my navbar's primary color?

Thanks

Comment: make sure they both are taking Blue in console, i'm doubtful about your navbar it's taking '#0275d8'

Comment: I guess, what I am asking is why accordion doesn't have a primary color for its headers.

Comment: In bootstrap 4 bg-primary class set #0275d8 and <a> default color is #0275d8 too, a:focus #014c8c. Perhaps you have another css changing this, inspect accordion <a> and see. If possible, provide a working example.

Comment: my bad, i didn't read it properly. @PiLHA is correct, make sure they both are taking "#0275d8" in your console